# How to retrieve datas by a filter based on a merged cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

In sheet1 (Source), I've a full calendar containing datas (dates in same row)

On 30/10/2022 in AM, SHIFT 1 has to work with ITEM A

On 30/10/2022 in PM, SHIFT 2 has to work with ITEM B... etc see snapshot below

[image]

In sheet2 (Results), I want to retrieve only the datas of only today and tomorrow

I used this formula for today:
=filter(Source!$B1:$G21,Source!$B1:$G1=TODAY())

and this one for tomorrow:
=filter(Source!$B1:$G21,Source!$B1:$G1=TODAY()+1)

But as you see in the snapshot below, there's only datas of the 1st column which are retrieved!!!!
[image]

Do u have an idea for showing whole datas, not only 1st column?

I share my work here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R49vFfk_L_tIOXm3q9dVGzwgHaSFde0Y3BHYGZokHlg/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance
Bazu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In b2 you can use this formula!

> =INDIRECT("source!R2C"&match(b1,source!$a$1:1,0)&":R5C"&match(b1,source!$a$1:1,0)+2,FALSE)

This way you're referring with Indirect to the range according to the match of the date!

Comment: This is for today. You can change +2 with +5 for the adjacent day

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin, it does the job!

Comment: Great! I'm glad!